# Writable ComboBox in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, combobox, drop-down-menu

How can we change a Silverlight ComboBox writable like in Windows Form when we change the DropDown property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the closest you can get is [autocompletebox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: I found a link which has implemented ComboBox Style on AutoCompleteBox I guss it's good http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/11/05/silverlight-editable-combobox-using-styles.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`ComboBox` in `Silverlight` does not have `IsReadonly` and `IsEditable` properties like `WPF` that allow it to be editable.

You will have to create a `custom control` or a `user control` to mimic that behavior.

Comment: yeah, you're right but what about the item template?? can't we use that?

Comment: `ItemTemplate` is for how each item is displayed inside your `ComboBox`. That won't help!